# Auto-increment as a counter in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I have a table with 3 columns (imageId, reportId, counter)
the primary key of the table is the columns (imageId, reportId)
now I want the counter columns will be the counter of how many times i've tried to insert the pair (imageId, reportId).

for example if i have the image "x.png" and 100 people reported that this image contains pornography, 
i want that the row in the table with the value ("x.png", "pornography") will have 100 in the counter column.
when the next person will report this image as pornography I want the counter to be 101 and so on.

how can i do such thing?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario it would be best to add new rows to your table. This means you can provide a view over the top of this which can select the counts as you require.

The benefit of a new row per report is the ability to also allow users to add custom messages etc.

-- Update

Some details here on views here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-syntax.html

At the heart of it your query will just be a basic query like

```
SELECT imageId, reportId, count(reportId) as count FROM training.reporttable group by imageId, reportId
```

Here is a basic example:

[image: Selecting counts of fields]

Note, I stuck with your example data but reportId and imageId should be normalised

Comment: Agreed, there's no reason to overly de-normalize this setup.  When a user submits the form, insert a record.  Don't pollute the storage of data with the concepts of the reporting on the data.  Store all records independently and create views over the data for reporting.

Comment: I don't need any cutmon messages from the user, i need the counter just for the admin of the image database to have some kind of priority of which image has been reported most

Comment: @user1851268 As David says, it is best to decouple business logic from your data. I was only offering another small benefit that can be gained by doing so

Comment: ok, how can i create views over the data? what does it means?

Comment: Updated my answer to show a basic query which you would then use in a view

Answer (score 2):

Use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (imageId, reportId, counter) VALUES (1, 1, 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET counter=counter+1
```

You could also set the default value of the counter column to 0 and use this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table (imageId, reportId) VALUES (1, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE SET counter=counter+1
```

Comment: tnx, I thought of something like that just didn't have any idea of how to do it